# Linux DST - 25.10.2020 - change did not occur - old linux bug?

Tags: linux, time, date

we have a strange problem on older linux kernel embedded devices that still uses /etc/tz and $TZ for setting the timezone and dst

Our TZ variable has value: 'MET-1MEDT,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/03:00

And yesterday the time did not go BACK as it should. Was this somekind of bug in DATE on older linux releases ? How to remedy this fast?

Or what?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. The zones are 'EET-2EEST,M3.5.0/3,M10.5.0/4'. It is a bug. Not sure exactly where.

It will change to MET (or EET) on 01.11.2020. You can wait. This is our solution since making/testing/distributing a patch will take loger.

You can set TZ to 'MET-1MEDT,M3.5.0,M10.4.0/03:00' to force MET time a week earlier. After 01.11 you should change back TZ to current value to keep it working in most cases.

Comment: Well the States have DST change this year on 1.11.2020.... Why we have 25.10. i don't know... But what i dont get why isn't the web burning with similar questions .... are we the only ones ?